# Problema al registrar dll usando regsvr32

Tags: vb6, regsvr32

**Transfondo:**

Estoy generando un proyecto de tipo `DLL Active X` usando Visual Basic 6 en un equipo con sistema operativo Windows 10 de 64 bits. Para ello, tuve que descargar [Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4AfPDbRSRY).

Este proyecto genera una DLL la cual valida que:

- Si existe el archivo **"CashRegister.exe"** en la ubicación **"C:\"** lo ejecuta; de lo contrario, muestra una alerta (es decir, un `MsgBox`) indicando que el archivo no existe.

He aquí el contenido de la clase (*código que he adaptado de esta [fuente](http://www.vb6.us/source-code/launch-program-vb)*):

```
Public Function AbrirExe()
    Dim Res
    Dim Filename
    Filename = "C:\CashRegister.exe"
    If Dir(Filename) = "" Then
        MsgBox ("El archivo no existe.")
    Else
        Res = Shell("CashRegister.exe" & Filename, vbHide)
    End If
End Function
```

Luego de consultar y seguir los pasos listados en las siguientes fuentes:

- [How to create ActiveX dll in vb6](https://youtu.be/9_YmzbP_xwc) *(video en Youtube)*.
- [Uso de la aplicación regsvr32.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/249873) *(en inglés)*.
- [Error 0x80004005 al registrar DLL con regsvr32.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413614/4092887).
- [Registrar una DLL](http://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html) *(en inglés)*.

Logré registrar la DLL:

[image: Registro de la DLL usando regsvr32.exe]

Pero, consultando la lista de DLL's registradas usando la herramienta "[RegDllView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registered_dll_view.html)" de NirSoft, la DLL **CashRegister.dll** no aparece listada.

**Problema:**

He realizado los mismos pasos para instalar otra DLL *(llamada **CashRegister35.dll**)* usando **regsvr32.exe**; esta otra DLL proviene de un sistema que está en funcionamiento, pero tampoco aparece listada.

No cuento con mas información sobre el contenido o la forma en que fue generada **CashRegister35.dll** y no encuentro mas información sobre cómo puedo registrar la DLL. He registrado ambas DLL's varias veces e incluso he reiniciado mi equipo, pero las DLL's siguen sin registrarse *(a pesar de que el mensaje así lo confirma)*.

**¿Cuál puede ser el problema con el registro de estas DLL's?**

---

Nota: Estoy siguiendo los pasos descritos en la página de [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229332(v=vs.60).aspx), pero sigo sin obtener los resultados esperados, si alguien conoce cómo generar una DLL en Visual Basic 6.0 puede generar su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al seguir los comentarios que recibí al [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38331605/4092887) en el sitio de Stack Overflow "en inglés", tuve que descartar el uso de la herramienta "RegDllView"; por lo que, el registro de la DLL **CashRegister35.dll** si fue registrada *tal y como el mensaje generado en la captura de pantalla anterior lo muestra*.

Se puede buscar directamente en el Registro **regedit.exe** por el nombre de la DLL.

Debido a que en su momento ejecuté varias veces la herramienta **regsvr32.exe**; la DLL fue registrada mas de una vez. No es recomendable modificar las entradas en el registro, por lo que tuve que ejecutar varias veces la siguiente linea:

```
regsrv32.exe \u CashRegister35.dll
```

A la vez que actualizaba el Registro (cerrar y abrir nuevamente el **regedit.exe**).